# Adding project reference in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I added a project reference of my Business Logic project to my console application. I can reference the project and its classes in the code of my console application. Weirdly, when I build the project, the build fails and the classes which referenced says Type is not defined.Has anybody come across an issue like this?

Comment: Have your tried building just your Business Logic project first, and then the console application? Perhaps the Business Logic project does not build and therefore not move a new DLL to your console application?

Comment: yes I tried it. No luck.

Comment: @Joshua:What type of project your ***Business Logic project ?*** Isn't it a `class library` project?

Comment: its a class library project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have selected the incorrect target framework .net framework client profile 4.0 where it should be .net framework 4. Issue rectified and now I can build the project.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import name space in your console application class where you are trying to use the business logic application class.

Comment: Then you have to show code file (.cs or .vb)  with which you are trying.